# How to call default list variables in terraform module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to call list variables from below code. But, It is throwing error instead after mentioning the default value in variables.tf

Terraform Service Folder (/root/terraform-ukg-smtp).

**main.tf**

```
module "google_uig" {
  source = "/root/terraform-google-vm/modules/compute_engine_uig"
  depends_on = [
    module.google_vm
  ]
  project     = var.project
  count       = var.num_instances
  zone        = var.zone == null ? data.google_compute_zones.available.names[count.index % length(data.google_compute_zones.available.names)] : var.zone
  name        = "apoc-uig-${random_integer.integer[count.index].result}"
  instances   = element((module.google_vm[*].google_instance_id), count.index)
  named_ports = var.named_ports
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "named_ports" {
  description = "Named name and named port"
  type = list(object({
    port_name   = string
    port_number = number
  }))
  default = [{
    port_name   = "smtp"
    port_number = "33"
  }]
}
```

Terraform Core Folder (/root/terraform-google-vm/modules/compute_engine_uig).

**main.tf**

```
# Instance Group
resource "google_compute_instance_group" "google_uig" {
  count     = var.num_instances
  project   = var.project
  zone      = var.zone
  name      = var.name
  instances = var.instances
  dynamic "named_port" {
    for_each = var.named_ports != null ? toset([1]) : toset([])
    content {
      name = named_port.value.port_name
      port = named_port.value.port_number
    }
  }
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "named_ports" {
  description = "Named name and named port"
  type = list(object({
    port_name = string
    port_number = number
  }))
  default = null
}
```

**ERROR**

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 66, in module "google_uig":
│   66:   port_number = each.value["port_number"]
│ 
│ An argument named "port_number" is not expected here.
```

Comment: Not a git question

Comment: You are obviously not showing the part where `each` is used as it is nowhere to be found in the code you added to the question except in the error.

Answer (score 2):

The error actually lies in the file `/root/terraform-google-vm/modules/compute_engine_uig/main.tf`, which you have not added to your question. But from the error message, I think to know what is wrong.

The resource `google_compute_instance_group.google_uig` in `compute_engine_uig/main.tf` should look like this:

```
resource "google_compute_instance_group" "google_uig" {
  other_keys = other_values

  dynamic "named_port" {
    for_each = var.named_ports
    content {
      name = named_port.value.name
      port = named_port.value.port
    }
  }
}
```

From the error message, it seems that you have written

```
name = named_ports.value.name
```

i.e., with a plural *s* instead of

```
name = named_port.value.name
```

in the `content` block.

If this doesn't solve it, please add the file that throws the error.

---

Edit from 30.05.2022:

Two more problems are now visible:

1. You set `for_each = var.named_ports != null ? toset([1]) : toset([])`, which is not correct. You have to iterate over `var.named_ports` (as I have written above), not over a set containing the number `1`. Just copy it word by word from the code above.
2. Additionaly, you have defined the type of `port_number` in your variable `named_ports` as "number", but you have given a string "33". This may be fine for terraform since it does a lot of conversion in the background, but better change it too.

Comment: You are correct @Dennis. I have removed 's' from code and now , It is throwing different error.

'''
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/google_uig/main.tf line 11, in resource "google_compute_instance_group" "google_uig":
│   11:       name = named_port.value.port_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ named_port.value is 1
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (number).
'''

Comment: I have updated the complete code with current modularized structure.

Comment: @SagarSaxena I have updated my answer to accommodate to the new error.

Comment: Thank You @DennisGrunert, Code is working as expected now. I was using wrong for_each iteration. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @SagarSaxena Gald to here. Since you have registered a new account: Maybe you then want to mark the answer as "accepted answer", see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers